# Angular12 Form validator is validating on load page

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I already search for all community and don't find any solution.

Have a form in angular inside of stepper.
The problem is when page is load, the form is validating on start, making the input in red color, like this:

[Image Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYPdx.png)

How can i prevent this?
I already try with markAsPristine and others, but, nothing...

Here is .TS part when initialize the form (it's call from ngOnInit):

```
this.professionalDataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  professionalRUT: this.formBuilder.control({value:'', disabled: false},[Validators.required]),
  professionalName: this.formBuilder.control({value:'', disabled: false}),
  address: this.formBuilder.control({value:'', disabled: false}),
  commune: this.formBuilder.control({value:'', disabled: false}),
  email: this.formBuilder.control({value:'', disabled: false})
});
```

And here the .html

```
<form [formGroup]="professionalDataForm">
<div class="row">
<mat-form-field class="col-md-4" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Rut del profesional</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="professionalRUT" >
<mat-error class="line-broken-tooltip">
   adsf
  </mat-error> 
</mat-form-field>
```

thnks...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's validating straight away, it's just that you need to control when `mat-error` should be shown or not. Looking at [the example for the `mat-form-field`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages), your issue could be resolved with a simple `ngIf`.

```html
<mat-form-field class="col-md-4" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Rut del profesional</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="professionalRUT" >
  <mat-error class="line-broken-tooltip" *ngIf="professionalDataForm.controls?.professionalRUT?.invalid">
   adsf
  </mat-error> 
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: i understand what you said, but, the problem is not if show or not show mat-error, becouse, if i delete <mat-error> tag, make the border of the input red anyway, i put de *ngIf... and show anyway, becouse when the page load is makin invalid the control, i don't know why

Comment: Usually this happens only if the field is also `touched`. Check which piece of code could make the input touched and go from there.